# wrong output in strings

Tags: c++, string

My program calculates the length of each word before space and compares it with a fixed number.
The number is chosen from another string (pi).

I don't know why but my variable FLAG is always set to false so I always get the same output.

I don't know where the problem is. Please help out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    int t=0,num;
    int i,j,len,space;
    bool FLAG;

    string pi ="31415926535897932384626433833",song;

    cin>>t;

    while(t--){

    len=0,space=0,i=0,j=0,num=0,FLAG=true;

    cin.ignore();

    getline(cin,song);

 // problem from here

      while(1) {

            i=0,num=0,FLAG=true;

            len=song.length();

            space=song.find(' ');

            if(space==-1){
                    if(len==pi[j]){
                            FLAG=true;
                            break;
                    }
                    else{
                            FLAG=false;
                            break;
                    }
            }

            else{

      while(i<space){
      num++;
      i++;
      }

      if(num==pi[j]){
            FLAG=true;
            j++;
            num=0;
            i=0;
            song.erase(0,space+1);
            cout<<song<<endl;
                     }

                else{
                    FLAG=false;
                    break;
                }
      }

    }

// to here


    if(FLAG==true){
        cout<<"It's a pi song."<<"\n";
    }

    else{
        cout<<"It's not a pi song."<<"\n";
    }

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: watch out for this line: `if (space == -1)` -1 is not guaranteed to be not found. `song.npos` is.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing an integer with a character value. i.e. you are comparing 3 with '3'. To get a number from a character digit, subtract '0'.

So you could write

```
if (len==(pi[j] - '0'))
```

Also, please learn to use a debugger, you can step through your code to find the line that doesn't work.